# In C#, how to convert the javascript's base64 string into a file

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core, angular-forms

In angular, I am making a form like this,

```
form = this.fb.group({
product_Id: [0]
product_Name: [''],
product_Image: ['']
})
```

Now I want to pass the product image in base64 string. So I have converted it using below,

```
fileSelected(files: FileList)
{
let file = <File>files[0]

let reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(file)
reader.onloadend = () => {
this.form.get('product_Image').setValue(reader.result)
}
}
```

---

On asp.net core side, I have implemented below logic,

```
var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "wwwroot\\Product\\test.jpg";

await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, Convert.FromBase64String(vm.Product_Image));
```

Now the asp.net core is giving me error: "The given format is not a valid base 64 string"

PS: I have also reader.readAsBinaryString(file) but the error is the same.

The Error: *The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.*

I don't know what wrong?

Comment: One possibility is that the base 64 encodings are using a different "key string", meaning they use different characters for specific bit combinations. Check if you can base 64 encode the same image file through the .NET code and see if the result is same.

Comment: Can you post what `vm.Product_Image` looks like ?

Comment: @CornelC Sure, it data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA...

Comment: Why are you using `data:` URIs at all? Why aren't you using the _much faster_ `Blob` API in JS?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) for **readAsDataURL**, you must remove the URI part before decoding.  I quote:

> **Note**: The blob's result cannot be directly decoded as Base64 without first removing the Data-URL declaration preceding the Base64-encoded data. To retrieve only the Base64 encoded string, first remove `data:*/*;base64,` from the result.

Answer (score 0):

try remove "data:image/jpeg;base64,"  from vm.Product_Image  string before

```
await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, Convert.FromBase64String(vm.Product_Image));
```

Sample base 64string as below

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKC...

Comment: This way I am getting an unauthorized access error. My path is "wwwroot\\test". I think I have to define the name of the file as well. But again, I want that to be from the file itself. Is there a way to process file first, rename the file so to add guid in the name, and then store?

Comment: @Bhavesh, unauthorized  access error related to your system. You must validate path before write. I believe it might string concatenation issue

Comment: Then how could get the name of this encoded file?